# Can include_bytes!() be used on a custom structure?

Tags: rust

I want to embed an image file in my project. To be more precise, I would like to embed the loaded Rust object containing the image, in my case a [`usvg::Tree`](https://docs.rs/usvg/0.5.0/x86_64-apple-darwin/usvg/struct.Tree.html), or even more advanced, a [`cairo::ImageSurface`](https://gtk-rs.org/docs/cairo/struct.ImageSurface.html). Would that be possible? I only find examples for `String`s.

Comment: include byte can include any byte so... anything, as your lib seem to have a `from_raw` function just use it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

From the documentation:

> Includes a file as a reference to a byte array.
>
> The file is located relative to the current file. (similarly to how
>   modules are found)
>
> This macro will yield an expression of type `&'static [u8; N]` which is
>   the contents of the file.

There is no restriction on the type of data. The literal bytes are included. It's worth recognizing that it's up to *you* to ensure that the bytes make sense for the platform that the code runs on and that you have some way of parsing the bytes.

See also:

- [Is there a good way to include external resource data into Rust source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25505275/155423)
- [Is there any way to include binary or text files in a Rust library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32748918/155423)
- [How to embed resources in Rust executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27140634/155423)