# Pushing a runtime operation to compile time in Rust?

Tags: rust, runtime, markdown, compile-time

I can [include external source markdown into the binary with `include_str!()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32749207/124486),

```
static HOME: &'static str = include_str!("../content/foo.md");
```

With this my yew application reads

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ecarroll ecarroll 111K Jun 14 19:58 ./static/wasm_bg.wasm
```

Now if I want to display that markdown as HTML, I can use the [`comrak`](https://docs.rs/comrak/0.7.0/comrak/) module and call `markdown_to_html`. This does exactly what I want,

```
 use comrak;
 comrak::markdown_to_html(HOME, &comrak::ComrakOptions::default())
```

Event though `HOME` is `static str` this results in a `1.3M` assembly (up from 111K`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ecarroll ecarroll 1.3M Jun 14 19:59 ./static/wasm_bg.wasm
```

Is there anyway in the language to push this calculation into compile-time and exclude all the `comrak` stuff from the runtime webassembly?

Comment: I didn't understand a thing but if you want build something at compile time look at build.rs

Comment: Yes, build a tool that converts the Markdown into HTML and then embed the resulting HTML into yoir binary (or better, load it from a file).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [build script (build.rs)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html). The [examples page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-script-examples.html) lists ["code generation"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-script-examples.html#code-generation) which you can probably adapt.