# How do I add resources such as text files or exe files into my application?

Tags: rust, resources

I tried this code

```
static HOST_FILE: &'static [u8] = include_bytes!("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\cbimage.png");

fn main() {
     let host_str = std::str::from_utf8(HOST_FILE). unwrap();

     println!("Hosts are:\n{}", &host_str[..42]);
}
```

But it shows me an error:
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Utf8Error { valid_up_to: 66, error_len: Some(1) }', src\main.rs:48:51
stack backtrace

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to include binary or text files in a Rust library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748918/is-there-any-way-to-include-binary-or-text-files-in-a-rust-library)

Comment: @Finomnis I tried it but it gives me an error
Utf8Error { valid_up_to: 0, error_len: Some(1) }'

Comment: @Finomnis
I tried the second example as well
And the error appeared:
byte index 42 is out of bounds of

Code:
static HOST_FILE: &'static str = include_str!("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\hello desktop. txt");

fn main() {
     println!("Hosts are:\n{}", &HOST_FILE[..42]);
}

The number 42 indicates what?

Comment: Your comments are turning the question into another question. Open a new one, with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including your code, the error messages, and the text file.

Comment: @Finomnis 
I'm currently with a single example that only contains this code
static HOST_FILE: &'static[u8] = include_bytes!("/etc/hosts");

fn main() {
     let host_str = std::str::from_utf8(HOST_FILE). unwrap();

     println!("Hosts are:\n{}", &host_str[..42]);
}
But it gives me an error!

Comment: Please don't use comments to update your question, [edit] your question directly :)

Comment: *"But it gives me an error!"* - Please don't make statements like this without actually showing the error. Just knowing that it fails on your machine gives us no information we could help you with.

Comment: I guess .. don't use the `42`? I'm not sure why that's part of the other question, but **never** copy-paste code from the internet into your project that you don't understand! Thats one of the very basic rules of stackoverflow. **Always** understand and verify code you copy from the internet. There are trolls, and there were cases where people made other people `sudo rm -rf /`.

Comment: Well now I've modified my question, I'll look into issue 42 and make sure

Comment: Why do you think a png file is valid utf8?

Comment: @cafce25 It's not utf8 but it wants to convert to pass include_bytes
Am i right ?

Comment: If it's not then why do you call `std::str::from_utf8` on it?

Comment: @cafce25 I've modified it now and removed  std::str::from_utf8
But he did not add the image to the application
why ?
fn main() {
       let bytes = include_bytes! ("C: \\ Users \\ Downloads \\ cbimage.png");
       println! ("{:?}" Byte) ;
}

Comment: Again, do NOT paste multi-line code in comments.

Comment: If you want to add to your question, you can [edit] it and add a tag like **EDIT:** in front of it. Like in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74665076/visual-studio-code-distorts-ansi-characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```rust
static IMAGE: &'static [u8] = include_bytes!("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\cbimage.png");

fn main() {
    println!("Image: {:?}", IMAGE);
}
```

Although I recommend using a path relative to your source code, like

```rust
static IMAGE: &'static [u8] = include_bytes!("../cbimage.png");

fn main() {
    println!("Image: {:?}", IMAGE);
}
```

And place `cbimage.png` next to your `Cargo.toml`.